# Upload VIdeo from feed dialog facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

hello i create a feed dialog on facebook

```
FB.ui({
         method:'feed',
         type: 'video',
         name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
         link: url,
         picture: image_url,
         caption: 'Reference Documentation',
         source: video_mp4_url,
         description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    });
```

but dont show a video on post

only show a image and icon play when a play icon dont show a video

my video are .mp4 extension
have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs, `source` can only be an `mp3` or `swf` flash file.

You either need to actually *upload* the video separately, or – if you are in control of the HTML code behind the link that is posted – embed the video via Open Graph meta tags directly, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video – then it will be playable directly in newsfeed. (Be aware, for that to work you need your video to be available via an HTTPS URL.)

Comment: Thanks! bad for me only have mp4 :/ jeje

Comment: You can use mp4 when embedding a video via Open Graph meta tags. And otherwise, I am sure converters that take your mp4 video and generate some kind of flash player from it are available on the net.